# How can I transfer the values of a 4D jagged array to a 2D standard array?

Tags: vba

I have EuroCPCrap mapped as (j,0)(i,0) and want to put this into an array EuroCPConsol mapped as (j,i). I tried:

```
For j = 0 to CPIndex 'CPIndex is a global count of variables in matrix j references
    For i = 0 to UBound (EuroCPCrap,3) 'i in the (now known to be) jagged
        EuroCPConsol(j+1,i+1)= EuroCPCrap(j,0,i,0) 'add one since I'm base 1 but function that produced this matrix outputted base zero
    Next i
Next j
```

I get a subscript error on the UBound statement, and I realised it's because there is no 3rd dimension in the referenced array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I don't understand why this `EuroCPCrap(j,0,i,0)` would work if it's a jagged array as you describe in your first sentence. On the looks of it, it should be `EuroCPCrap(j,0)(i,0)`.

You have a parent two-dimensional array of children two-dimensional arrays. The "third" dimension you're looking for is actually the first dimension of each child array. So something like this should work:

```
For i = 0 to UBound(EuroCPCrap(j,0),1)
```

Actually, iterating from `LBound` to `UBound` is even better practice to ensure that the entire array is traversed regardless of your `Option Base` or how the array is "Dimmed":

```
For i = LBound(EuroCPCrap(j,0),1) to UBound(EuroCPCrap(j,0),1)
```

Does `EuroCPCrap` really need to be jagged? Why not make it a 4-dimensional array? `EuroCPConsol` is not jagged... Is it dimensioned correctly to accept the contents of the largest of the children array? These are things to think about...

Comment: EuroCPCrap is a Nanex output; ideally it wouldn't be jagged but that's how they UDP the data to us. Since two of the dimensions are empty I'm just collapsing it to the 2 dimensions it should have been in the first place. 

Is there a simpler way to determine the largest of the child arrays than UBound looping through the parent array?